# Hiding codebehind files on web server( hiding programming logic)

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing

We are publishing our website using VS10

1) While publishing the website Localy,  only aspx files are  grouped together in the published folder and that web is working fine in the local  `IIS server`.

2)though  .cs  files are not in the published folder all the events are working well in Local iis server

3)what I am doing..... I am coping that published web folder and uploaded it to the  web server.

4)but now it showing an error for every event I calling????

5) how can I tackle this problem??

6) For security reason I don't want to upload my code behind files to web server?? I want to hide my programing logic how can I do this ????

7) when I am uploading my web with both the .cs and aspx files it working well but I don't want to do this??

Comment: `"but now it showing an error for every event i calling?"` What is it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to publish your website it will generate dll put that instead of putting .cs files. This codeproject [**article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53075/How-to-deploy-ASP-NET-Web-Application-on-server) explains how to do it.

Comment: You are welcome, meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy all of the files. You only need to upload the **.ASPX** file and the **Bin** folder which will contain the compiled logic in a DLL named YourProject.DLL and also any other references that are required. The **.CS** files containing your actual code are not required on the server as they have been compiled into the DLL.

With JavaScript you cannot hide this from the user because it is needed on the client-side. However, you should save all of your JavaScript into a **.JS** file and include on the page. At least it makes it less obvious to someone viewing the source of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing your web site will do the job.

Please read [How to: Publish Web Sites (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

and

[ASP.NET Web Site Project Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)